# Visual Studio 2015 projects start at 15mb

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as I can't seem to find anything about it over the last few days.

We're currently looking at upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015.  Whenever creating a new ASP.Net project, the project immediately starts at 15mb where previously it was only a few kb.

Items of note are the inclusion of the following files causing the project to bloat:

- `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0.nupkg` file at 4.26mb
- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll` at 1.68mb
- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll` at 3.90mb
- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll` at 4.79mb

  1. Why are these files now being included in VS 2015?
  2. From what I have found online, the Compilers nugget contains the exact compiler to use on the project, though I can't figure out why it's not like all previous versions of VS as I'm running 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015 on the same box and until now the others have worked just fine.
  3. I get the code analysis, but trying to create a quick example project completely bloats the project when I'm not even interested in it.  Also, why is both C# AND VB included when the project is only using C# for example?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be related to the Roslyn Compiler as indicated [by this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/2070002.aspx?ASP+Net+5+Visual+Studio+2015+projects+start+at+15mb).  It really "feels" like VS2015 wasn't quite ready to be nudged out the nest but we'll see what update 1 holds.

For now I'll create VS2013 projects, upgrade them to 2015 and then check them into Source Control and continue from there.